# How to retrieve google place details for multiple places (placeids)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is it possible to retrieve place details for multiple places?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=[ArrayInsteadOfJustOnePlaceId]
```

The documentation does not mention anything regarding the resolving of multiple places.

[google places doc](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsRequests)

Comment: Not in a single request.  You need to make multiple requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in a single request. 
You have to iterate over a list of place id and make a call for each.

Here is a sample code to do it using this python wrapper: 
[/slimkrazy/python-google-places](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places)

```sh
pip install python-google-places
```

```py
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, GooglePlacesAttributeError, GooglePlacesError

GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDRcaVMH1F_H3pIbm1T-XXXXXXXXXXX'
GOOGLE_PLACE_IDS = [
    "ChIJC4Wu9QmvthIRDmojjnJB6rA",
    "ChIJuRFUv33Ew0cRk0JQb2xQOfs",
    "ChIJ9yGYrIwd9kcRlV-tE8ixHpw"
  ]

def main():
 google_places = GooglePlaces(GOOGLE_API_KEY)
 for place_id in GOOGLE_PLACE_IDS:
     try:
         place = google_places.get_place(place_id)
         print('{0} place_id has name {1}'.format(place_id, place.name))

     except (GooglePlacesError, GooglePlacesAttributeError) as error_detail:
         print('Google Returned an Error : {0} for Place ID : {1}'.format(error_detail, place_id))
         pass
```

Comment: it's a solution, but i think it's a bad one :(

Comment: I did not find any solution by myself and iterate gives an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT ...